# Create a link to a table in an MS Access database using vbscript

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I would like some vbscript code to run in a Data Access Page.  The code is to create a link to a table in another access database.

In the data access page, I am already connected to my current database, so hopefully I just need to specify the external access database path and name, then the table that I would like to link to, and the name of the link...  this would be the ideal solution.

I've spent hours looking around, but all I can find is VBA and/or code to perform this in access modules that can be called by forms.

Is there a way to do this?  I can manually create links using the 'new table' wizard but I need code to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. Please show us what you have tried, and explain what *specific* problem you encountered.

Comment: my actual question is "is there a way to do this?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible with VBS.  You say that you have seen some VBA code and modules.  Well most of those VBA code / modules can be used in vbs as well with a little bit of tweaking.

For example let's say you had some vba code that was like `Set myRs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("someTbl_or_someQry")`

Well in VBS you first need access to the Microsoft Office Access Application object.

To do so depends on if you are planning to execute the vbs while the access database in question is open at the time or not.

If the database is not open then you do the following at the beginning of your VBS:

`myAccessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")`

Otherwise:

`myAccessApp = GetObject(,"Access.Application")`

Now that you have an Access.Application object loaded you can now do nearly anything you would be able to do with VBA, the only difference is that you will add your application object to the beginning of the relevant VBA code lines.  So now thus you could:

`Set myRS = myAccessApp.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SomeTbl_or_somQry")`

In your VBS file.

Bottom line: Yes it is possible once your VBS has access to an Access.Application object.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you, Sean W.  That's given me a good insight as to a way forward and also highlights some limitations that I may encounter... e.g. some of the users of my application don't actually have Access installed - instead, they use MS Office Web Components.  So at least I can see who can/cant make use of my forthcoming solution, which I can cater for with my code.  Thanks again

Comment: Sounds great. I am glad that I was able to help. Would you be willing to click the accepted answer button for this question?